# access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org2MSP]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Im trying to setup a hyperledger fabric network wtih 2 organizations base on byfn. The network consist of the following nodes:

```
cli 
peer1.org1.example.com 
peer0.org2.example.com 
peer1.org2.example.com 
peer0.org1.example.com 
orderer.example.com 
couchdb3 
couchdb2 
couchdb1 
ca.org1.example.com 
couchdb0 
ca.org2.example.com
```

I using fabcar chaincode for this network and have no problem enrolling Admin, registering User and query from peer in Org1.

But when i try to perform the same query from a peer in Org2, I get the following error :

*Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org2MSP]*

Would like to ask if anyone know what this error means and how can I fix this?

Following are the steps and configuration files I have used:

```
./byfn.sh -m down

# clean the keystore
rm -rf ./hfc-key-store
rm -rf ./hfc-key-store2

#Generate artifacts
../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
export CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel  && ../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org1MSP
../bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsChannel -outputAnchorPeersUpdate ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME -asOrg Org2MSP
```

Then replace ca0 and ca1 keyfile in docker-compose-cli.yaml :

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.example.com:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
  peer1.org1.example.com:
  peer0.org2.example.com:
  peer1.org2.example.com:

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/f6aa4b99b3177c86e00e55e4ed5dea88ec0c67f27327955eb978b9bf80d6116e_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/e6a77b168161b5032d393f9590ad6e61c9d4cde51ca6cfeb8b9dc4d1932b2be9_sk
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      #- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      #- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      #- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      #- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Then run the following to setup the network and install the chaincodes

```
#Startup dockers
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml -f docker-compose-couch.yaml up -d
sleep 30

docker exec cli peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx
sleep 10
docker exec cli peer channel join -b mychannel.block

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" cli peer channel join -b mychannel.block

docker exec cli peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1MSPanchors.tx 

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" cli peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/Org2MSPanchors.tx

#Install chaincode
docker exec cli peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/fabcar/go

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051" -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP" cli peer chaincode install -n fabcar -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/fabcar/go

docker exec cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
sleep 10
docker exec cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[""]}'
```

Next I run node enrollAdmin.js

```
'use strict';
/*
* Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
*
* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
/*
 * Enroll the admin user
 */

var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
var Fabric_CA_Client = require('fabric-ca-client');

var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var os = require('os');

//
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();
var fabric_ca_client = null;
var admin_user = null;
var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store2');
console.log(' Store path:'+store_path);

// create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
}).then((state_store) => {
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);
    var tlsOptions = {
        trustedRoots: [],
        verify: false
    };
    // be sure to change the http to https when the CA is running TLS enabled
    fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:8054', tlsOptions , 'ca-org2', crypto_suite);

    // first check to see if the admin is already enrolled
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
        console.log('Successfully loaded admin from persistence');
        admin_user = user_from_store;
        return null;
    } else {
        // need to enroll it with CA server
        return fabric_ca_client.enroll({
          enrollmentID: 'admin',
          enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw'
        }).then((enrollment) => {
          console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin"');
          return fabric_client.createUser(
              {username: 'admin',
                  mspid: 'Org2MSP',
                  cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate }
              });
        }).then((user) => {
          admin_user = user;
          return fabric_client.setUserContext(admin_user);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.error('Failed to enroll and persist admin. Error: ' + err.stack ? err.stack : err);
          throw new Error('Failed to enroll admin');
        });
    }
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Assigned the admin user to the fabric client ::' + admin_user.toString());
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Failed to enroll admin: ' + err);
});
```

Then run node registerUser.js

```
'use strict';
/*
* Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
*
* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
/*
 * Register and Enroll a user
 */

var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
var Fabric_CA_Client = require('fabric-ca-client');

var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var os = require('os');

//
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();
var fabric_ca_client = null;
var admin_user = null;
var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store2');
console.log(' Store path:'+store_path);

// create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
}).then((state_store) => {
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);
    var tlsOptions = {
        trustedRoots: [],
        verify: false
    };
    // be sure to change the http to https when the CA is running TLS enabled
    fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:8054', null , '', crypto_suite);

    // first check to see if the admin is already enrolled
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
        console.log('Successfully loaded admin from persistence');
        admin_user = user_from_store;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to get admin.... run enrollAdmin.js');
    }

    // at this point we should have the admin user
    // first need to register the user with the CA server
    return fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'User1', affiliation: 'org2.department1',role: 'client'}, admin_user);
}).then((secret) => {
    // next we need to enroll the user with CA server
    console.log('Successfully registered user2 - secret:'+ secret);

    return fabric_ca_client.enroll({enrollmentID: 'User1', enrollmentSecret: secret});
}).then((enrollment) => {
  console.log('Successfully enrolled member user "User1" ');
  return fabric_client.createUser(
     {username: 'User1',
     mspid: 'Org2MSP',
     cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate }
     });
}).then((user) => {
     member_user = user;

     return fabric_client.setUserContext(member_user);
}).then(()=>{
     console.log('User1 was successfully registered and enrolled and is ready to intreact with the fabric network');

}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Failed to register: ' + err);
    if(err.toString().indexOf('Authorization') > -1) {
        console.error('Authorization failures may be caused by having admin credentials from a previous CA instance.\n' +
        'Try again after deleting the contents of the store directory '+store_path);
    }
});
```

Then node query.js

```
'use strict';
/*
* Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
*
* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/
/*
 * Chaincode query
 */

var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
var path = require('path');
var util = require('util');
var os = require('os');

//
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

// setup the fabric network
var channel = fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel');
var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:9051');
channel.addPeer(peer);

//
var member_user = null;
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store2');
console.log('Store path:'+store_path);
var tx_id = null;

// create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
}).then((state_store) => {
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

    // get the enrolled user from persistence, this user will sign all requests
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('User1', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
        console.log('Successfully loaded User1 from persistence');
        member_user = user_from_store;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to get User1.... run registerUser.js');
    }
console.log('1');
    // queryCar chaincode function - requires 1 argument, ex: args: ['CAR4'],
    // queryAllCars chaincode function - requires no arguments , ex: args: [''],
    const request = {
        //targets : --- letting this default to the peers assigned to the channel
        chaincodeId: 'fabcar',
        fcn: 'queryAllCars',
        args: ['']
    };
console.log('2');
    // send the query proposal to the peer
    return channel.queryByChaincode(request);
}).then((query_responses) => {
    console.log("Query has completed, checking results");
    // query_responses could have more than one  results if there multiple peers were used as targets
    if (query_responses && query_responses.length == 1) {
        if (query_responses[0] instanceof Error) {
            console.error("error from query = ", query_responses[0]);
        } else {
            console.log("Response is ", query_responses[0].toString());
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No payloads were returned from query");
    }
}).catch((err) => {
console.log('3');
    console.error('Failed to query successfully :: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your channel configuration in `configtx.yaml` file.

Check if `Org2` is part of the channel or not.

```
TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Check if the `fabcar` chaincode is installed on `Org2` or not.

If you're using `network-config.yaml` like `balance-transfer` then check if peer has access to query the ledger or not.

```
peer0.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running these two organisations in separate machines?If so then you may have to copy the crypto materials . You can follow the link [here](https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/) for multiple machine setup for single organisation.

Comment: Im trying to setup 2 organisations on 1 machine.I manage to get Org1's query to work but somehow Org2's query return error.

Comment: Please go through the link and add accordingly.http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html .I think you have to use configtxlator for adding another org to your channel.

Comment: Im using byfn to setup the network. Org1 and Org2 should already be configured to be part of the channel in configtx.yaml, I should not need to add Org2 to the channel again?

Comment: Added Org3 according to http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/channel_update_tutorial.html . But get the same error : Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [Org3MSP]

Answer (score 0):

@ze9620, Your CLI environment variables configured for peer0 of org1, i think you can try by creating once more cli instance which contains evironmentals related to peer of org2 which may give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue from both a Java and NodeJS perspective. I noticed that when I was running the startFabric.sh in the fabcar directory that I was seeing:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e
```

> "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block
>   Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

so I did this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52611722/10603426 and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is initially when you run the `docker-compose` file only the environment variables for `ORG1` is set up and the peer(s) from `ORG1`is joined to the channel. You could try to do the same for `ORG2` inside the `cli` container and make sure that the peer from `ORG2` joins the channel using

```
peer channel join -b $CHANNEL_NAME.block
```

Hope this works. Good luck!